# Using requests, how to iterate dictions to get data

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

DATA to be search through:

```
{
  "epicUserHandle": "HaaZeeY",
  "stats": {
    "p2": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1193,
        "value": "1193",
        "rank": 3210238,
        "percentile": 56.0,
        "displayValue": "1,193"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 46,
        "value": "46",
        "rank": 15163718,
        "percentile": 0.8,
        "displayValue": "46"
      },
```

My code:

```
url = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{}/{}".format(platform, 
username)
headers = {'TRN-Api-Key' : 'MY API KEY'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#p2 = Solo
#p10 = Duo
#p9 = Squad

tempory_dict = {}

result = r.json()['stats']['p2']['top1']

for r in result:
    #WHAT DO I PUT HERE

tempory_dict['Wins'] = #VALUE

print(tempory_dict['Wins'])
```

What do I need to do here? I want it to find the `"value"` and save that in the `tempory_dict['Wins']`. I'm new to requests and not sure how to iterate through it all to find value.

Thanks.

Comment: How would this be any different than getting `'stats'` out of the dictionary returned by `r.json()`, or getting `'p2'` out of the dictionary that is `'stats'`, or getting `'top1'` out of the dictionary that is `'p2'`?

Comment: I have never really worked with dictionaryd so I don't fully understand what your saying?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is a good place to start, then.  You can learn about dictionaries and all other parts about the language you're programming in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there actually, having:
`result = r.json()['stats']['p2']['top1']`, you actually assign
`{
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 46,
        "value": "46",
        "rank": 15163718,
        "percentile": 0.8,
        "displayValue": "46"
}`
to `result` variable, so all you need to do is just go one step further and assign: 
`tempory_dict['Wins'] = result['value']`